# beforeUpdate doesn't seem to be called

Tags: javascript, node.js, passwords, hook, sequelize.js

*I have a simple user model as follows :*

```
'use strict';

let hashPassword = (user, options) => {
    if (!user.changed('password')) { return; }
    return require('bcrypt')
        .hash(user.getDataValue('password'), 10)
        .then(hash => user.setDataValue('password', hash));
};

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        username: {allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
        email: {allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
        password: {allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: false},
    }, {
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: hashPassword,
            beforeUpdate: hashPassword
        }
    });
    return User;
};
```

It works very well on user creation, but the `beforeUpdate` hook doesn't seem to work or be called, and the password is saved in plain text in the database.

**Where does it come from and how can it be fixed ?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How are you updating the user? There is a difference between getting an instance of the user and updating it and updating by querying the model. The former is an **instance** update and the latter a **bulk** update operation (even if your `where` filter would return a single item).

This distinction is important because `beforeUpdate` is an [instance hook](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html) so it would be triggered on instance updates only. You can either change the way you update the user or implement a `beforeBulkUpdate` hook as well.

Comment: It looks like you are right, I use `db.user.update(..., {where: {id: req.params.userId}});`. Thank you very much

Comment: can you post sample code, because i can't find what parameters actually are

Answer (score 1):

To offer an alternative to Unglückspilz answer.  You can also add the option

```
{ individualHooks: true }
```

> Note: methods like bulkCreate do not emit individual hooks by default - only the bulk hooks. However, if you want individual hooks to be emitted as well, you can pass the { individualHooks: true } option to the query call. However, this can drastically impact performance, depending on the number of records involved (since, among other things, all instances will be loaded into memory).

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#model-hooks

Comment: const user = await User.update(req.body,{ where: { id }, individualHooks: true});